# How to get information about descending order of elements from a square matrix

Tags: python

I have a square matrix which is basically a correlation matrix, so all the elements are in the range of `-1` to `+1`. I need to sort the elements within some range say `0.5` to `0.75` in descending order with the information of coordinate. I need the coordinate to build a network.

Here is my `3*3` matrix:

```py
a = array([
    [1, 0.7, 0.3],
    [0.65, 1, 0.86],
    [0.67, 0.53, 1]
])
```

I am a newbie here.

I am expecting my result as :

```
the coordinate  of 0.7 (0, 1)
the coordinate of 0.67 (2, 0)
the coordinate of 0.65 (1, 0)
the coordinate of 0.53 (2, 1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to solving this problem yourself?

Comment: Where exactly is the sorting required? Isn't it more of filtering than sorting?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami, basically filtering + sorting (sorting in the reverse order of numbers in the range 0.5 to 0.75).

Comment: I can find out maximum or minimum value with np.where or np.argwhere with coordinate. but unable to do it within some range

Comment: The `array` can be traversed and then the values can be stored in a list along with their positions, like, `[(0.7, (0, 1)), ... ]` and then this list can be simply sorted using `.sort()` I'm sorry I don't feel like writing the code. xD

Answer (score 1):

My advice is that - As a programmer you should able to build your own logic to approach any problem.

but the solution for your problem is here :

```py
mat = [
    [1, 0.7, 0.3],
    [0.65,1,0.86],
    [0.67, 0.53, 1]
]

ls = []

for row in range(len(mat)):
    for col in range(len(rows)):
          if 0.5 <= a[row][col] <= 0.76:
              ls.append((a[row][col],(row,col)))

ls.sort(reverse=True)
dic = dict(ls)

for key in dic.keys():
    print("the coordinate of ",key,dic[key])
```

The output will :

```
the coordinate of  0.7 (0, 1)
the coordinate of  0.67 (2, 0)
the coordinate of  0.65 (1, 0)
the coordinate of  0.53 (2, 1)
```

Comment: thanks for kind reply. with your help i m able to produce the answer like this          the coordinate of  0.7 (0, 1)
the coordinate of  0.3 (0, 2)
the coordinate of  0.65 (1, 0)
the coordinate of  0.86 (1, 2)
the coordinate of  0.67 (2, 0)
the coordinate of  0.53 (2, 1)    with modified range 0.3 to 0.9. but i need them descending order. my actual matrix size is 500*500.

Comment: I have changed the code. Sorry I forget to write the line for sorting there